# Only 5 Unique IP addres is allowed to visit website concurrently mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I got one confusing requirement. I am working on one MVC application.
Now the requirement is the web application can allowed only 5 concurrent unique visitors each time when some one leaves then the next visitor can able to access it.
But if there is already 5 user actively accessing it no one can access it. if new user trying to access he will get message no quota available check back again in while.

So how can I do it in MVC? Need a suggestions ;)

Thank you.

Comment: If it was me I would use something like SignalR. I would create a landing page which would display a queue number, and when a user leaves the next in line would get redirected.

Comment: @MartinM and how SignalR helps in this situation?

Comment: @teovankot SignalR helps you by keeping track of who is online. If you used something like session you wouldnt always get proper information about when someone leaves the page.

Comment: @MartinM: Please do u have any reference of signalR.

Comment: @MayurLohite and can 2 users use 1 IP?

Comment: @MartinM yes its allowed because its one same LAN? So no worry

Comment: @MayurLohite What kind of reference are you looking for? Something like [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/dotnetConf/2014/SignalR)?

Comment: @MartinM: Thank for your hint. Not to worry I will googe it.

Comment: You can configure concurrent connections in IIS

Comment: @AshleyMedway the concurrent users are some criteria sometimes its 5 or sometimes its 10. as per URL the users will change.